# Jupyter Extension Publish

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

i have created custom extension and try to publish on jupyter lab and notebook so any idea about publishing jupyter extension...
I have created Python package for extension on pypi https://pypi.org/

Comment: What is your question then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should build your package, according this tutorial which is for main site of **Jupyterlab**, this [link](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html#packaging-your-extension) :

```
python -m build
```

After that inside your main directory, it will create this folder: **/dist**.

in the *dist* folder you should find a **.whl** file.

So, install twine package:

```
pip install twine
```

After that you can upload easily with this command:

```
twine upload file_name.whl
```

It will ask you the username and password which you should create on pypi.org website.